# Can I add testers to an app in App Store Connect when my app is in "Prepare for Submission" status?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

My app is in "Prepare for Submission" and I'd like to add testers (either internal or external, doesn't matter to me) but I'm not sure how to get that done because a lot of options disappear once the app is in a "Prepare for Submission" state. Are there any known workarounds/fixes for this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Now that your app is in that state, head over to the TestFlight tab (at this time, located at near the top of the screen) and set up your testers, groups, etc, and provide export compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong - previously, the app was built and uploaded to App Store Connect, then was added to a new version of the iOS app where it said "Prepare for Submission."

The fix was to remove the build from the new version of the app (in my case, 1.2), re-upload it, but before adding it to the new version you can find it in TestFlight > Builds, then it opens up all of the options and you can easily add testers. To add external testers you'll need to submit the beta to review to apple.